# Why exported variables in Makefile is not received by executable?

Tags: linux, makefile, export

I have a makefile, where i am exporting variables which will be received by an executable, but surprisingly the executable is not receiving the exported values.

Please help me.

```
31 test:
32         @ echo
33         @ echo "Testing Electric Fence."
34         @ echo "After the last test, it should print that the test has PASSED."
35         ./eftest
36         ./tstheap 3072
37         export EF_ERRTRACK_START=3
38         export EF_ERRTRACK_END=5
39         ./time-interval-measurement-test
40         @ echo
41         @ echo "Electric Fence confidence test PASSED." 
42         @ echo
```

`time-interval-measurement-test` is an executable (C program) which should receive the exported variables, but it is not getting. Please help me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken each line in a Makefile is a separate shell-process. So shell-export does not work for several processes: One way to do it is to put them into one line:

```
test:
         @ echo
         @ echo "Testing Electric Fence."
         @ echo "After the last test, it should print that the test has PASSED."
         ./eftest
         ./tstheap 3072
         EF_ERRTRACK_START=3 EF_ERRTRACK_END=5 ./time-interval-measurement-test
         @ echo
         @ echo "Electric Fence confidence test PASSED." 
         @ echo
```

or line-break-escaped with '\'

```
test:
        [..]
        EF_ERRTRACK_START=3 \
        EF_ERRTRACK_END=5 \
        ./time-interval-measurement-test
```

Like that the ENV-variables are available to ./time-interval-measrument

Comment: :Let me try both the ways and quickly tell you the results.

Comment: Sorry, this is what happened. export EF_ERRTRACK_START=3 export EF_ERRTRACK_END=5 ./time-interval-measurement-test

/bin/sh: line 0: export: `./time-interval-measurement-test': not a valid identifier

make: *** [test] Error 1

Comment: Testing Electric Fence.

After the last test, it should print that the test has PASSED.

./eftest



  Electric Fence 2.1 Copyright (C) 1987-1998 Bruce Perens.

./tstheap 3072



  Electric Fence 2.1 Copyright (C) 1987-1998 Bruce Perens.

export EF_ERRTRACK_START=3 export EF_ERRTRACK_END=5 ./time-interval-measurement-test

/bin/sh: line 0: export: `./time-interval-measurement-test': not a valid identifier

make: *** [test] Error 1

-bash-3.2# make test

Comment: Thanks it worked, i forgot to remove the `export` before the variable name.

Answer (score 2):

I had asked for a similar question, but its not the exact same scenario
[how to implement makefile shared variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231051/how-to-implement-makefile-shared-variable)

Ideally your exported variables should have passed on to the child process, I wonder if your child shell is same as parent.

Try following -
export EF_ERRTRACK_START=3; export EF_ERRTRACK_END=5; ./time-interval-measurement-test

Comment: Thanks, Yes, using the semicolon also works..upvote for you. Came to know of a new method apart from the first one.