# Export current user id in makefile for docker-compose

Tags: docker, makefile, docker-compose

I trying to pass the current user id into `docker-compose.yml`

How it looks in `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    app:
        build:
            context: ./
            target: "php-${APP_ENV}"
        user: "${CURRENT_UID}"
```

Instead of `CURRENT_UID=$(id -u):$(id -g) docker-compose up -d` I've wrote makefile

```
#!/usr/bin/make

SHELL = /bin/sh

up: 
    export CURRENT_UID=$(id -u):$(id -g)
    docker-compose up -d
```

But `CURRENT_UID` still empty when I run `make up`

Is there a possible export uid in makefile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why exported variables in Makefile is not received by executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995107/why-exported-variables-in-makefile-is-not-received-by-executable)

Comment: The `export` and the command you're running need to be on the same Makefile line.  (The same is true for Dockerfile `RUN` commands for the same reason.)

Comment: Don't work https://gist.github.com/matchish/ed0f03bc58d73eb2e94876a512d4205a

Comment: I got output  
`export CURRENT_UID=: && echo`

Comment: `$(VARIABLE)` is Make expansion syntax.  You need `$$` to inject a dollar sign, or the GNU make `$(shell command ...)` extension.

Comment: Do not use `$(shell ...)` inside a recipe.  It is unnecessary and simply creates confusion.

Comment: Thanks, guys. You've helped me a lot

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is my solution

```
#!/usr/bin/make

SHELL = /bin/sh

CURRENT_UID := $(shell id -u)
CURRENT_GID := $(shell id -g)

export CURRENT_UID
export CURRENT_GID

up: 

    docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: This solution solved for me. Thanks! I just changed by setting like this: `docker run -u ${CURRENT_UID}:${CURRENT_UID} ... `

Comment: What does the SHELL variable do? Bash scripting is case sensitive after all?

Comment: Yes! Been looking for this for over an hour! thanks. Works directly in a Makefile w/o the SHELL = /bin/sh part

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/589300/4175647 says what does SHELL variable do

Comment: What happens if the user has changed their group with `newgrp`. Using `$(shell id -g)` will create a new sub-shell and return the default group not the current group, won't it?

Comment: @ricoms there is a typo on your comment, it should be ${CURRENT_UID}:${CURRENT_**G**ID}

Comment: @andré-ricardo, thanks for correction, you are right

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use `env`:

Makefile:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

UID := $(shell id -u)

up:
    env UID=${UID} docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 2 dollar signs ($$) before (id -u) and (id -g).

```
#!/usr/bin/make

SHELL = /bin/sh

up: 
    export CURRENT_UID=$$(id -u):$$(id -g)
    docker-compose up -d
```